# Any advice on technical analysis of financial data?

Tags: machine-learning, multivariate-analysis, finance

we're looking for any software/framework that is able to analyse the financial flux?

*Some preliminaries*. We've been asked by one of our customer to find or develop the software that would solve some their problems. The firm selling a lot of small staff (food elements for animals) in enormous quantity. The problem is to track the financial activity/history of a single client. That is we've been asked to develop some analytical system that would produce alerts once the anomalous behaviour detected.

So, not being an expert at all in this area, I'm asking you for an advice whether you know any software or package that is able to produce some kind of [candlestick chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candlestick_chart) and make some basic analysis on that datasets.

I've been looking for Matlab, R, SciPy packages but **need** you advice on where to start and what to choose? And whether it can been done in a reasonable time or maybe the problem posed is to complex?

The final idea was to have an operator that would continuously checking the financial activity using the dashboard or something and interrupt the order on the suspicious behaviour. So the system will **not** function in an absolutely autonomous manner but have to posses the possibility to accept operator's feedback and learn on errors.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really a statistics question, but one of practical software development.

Since it sounds you're probably going to slap a GUI on whatever backend code you write you will want to avoid [MATLAB](https://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab.html) at all costs.

Here's why: 1) MATLAB's plotting functionality is great. Writing a GUI that uses that functionality is about as unintuitive as it gets. 2) If I'm not mistaken you have to run some sort of proprietary engine to have a standalone application.

Your best bet given the packages you listed and your problem is probably going to be [Python](https://www.python.org/) with [NumPy](https://numpy.org), [SciPy](https://scipy.org/) and [Matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/). It's almost trivial to get a GUI up and running in Python. Additionally, I've found that it's (mostly) very easy to tie many different pieces code together.

All that being said, I have virtually no experience with [R](https://www.r-project.org/), so maybe that has some additional benefits that go above and beyond the tools I just mentioned.

Comment: With regards to R, I would say it's pretty much equivalent to Python in terms of capabilities. The main tradeoff would be that Python is often quite more performant, while R software is faster to produce